# How can I subtract and calculate the complement of a pair of sets?

Tags: syntax, boolean-computation, sets, subset

I cannot properly implement these operations. How can I do it?

This is a reduced example:

```
A={2,3,4}
B={2,4,6}
C={1,2,3,4}
```

Find

```
P = [(C-A) U(C-B)] U [(B-A) U (B-C)]
```

I'm looking for the difference between two sets of numbers, just like in school
"A-B is everything that is in A and not in B"

Q= [(C U A)^'# (B -C)^´]^´, with # and equal to the symmetrical difference

This symbol ^´ is the complement of a set.

Comment: `C` is a reserved symbol. Can use all lower case letters in your post. The equation for `Q` is not clear. Please use set notation. What is `#` in set notation? and what is `'`?

Comment: That complement requires a universal set that is not specified in the OP. I meant to draw attention to `^'` and the `#`.

Comment: The Universe is A U B U C

Comment: `Union` and `Complement` are not difficult to find in the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [Mathematica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfram_Mathematica), your P and Q can be written as:

```
P = Complement[b, c] ⋃ Complement[c, a ⋂ b];
Q = Complement[b, a] ⋃ Complement[a, b] ⋃ c;
```

To avoid mistakes when I simplified the expressions, I used

```
Table[Complement[b, a] ⋃ Complement[a, b] ⋃ c ===
    Complement[Complement[Range[10], c ⋃ a], Complement[Range[10], Complement[b, c]]] ⋃
    Complement[Complement[Range[10], Complement[b, c]], Complement[Range[10], c ⋃ a]],
{a, Subsets[Range[6]]}, {b, Subsets[Range[6]]}, {c, Subsets[Range[6]]}] // Flatten // Tally
```

to compare with your exact expression.

Answer (score 4):

First, do not use capital letters for variables, because capitalized names are used by the system.

A set difference, e.g. c-a, is written by: Complement[c, a]. A set union, e.g. of a and b, is written by : Union[a,b] or for short [image: a\[Union\]b] where the special character is typed by ESC un ESC. Therefore,e.g.:

```
a = {2, 3, 4}; b = {2, 4, 6}; c = {1, 2, 3, 4};
p = Union[Complement[c, a], Complement[c, b], Complement[b, a], 
  Complement[b, c]]
(*{1, 3, 6}*)
```

Comment: hi , if A set difference,  between  c-a, is written by: Complement[c, a] , then how do you write the complement between c U a , And how do you write the symmetric difference?How do you calculate a-b-c?

Comment: "complement between c U a" ??? symmetric difference: Union-Intersection. a-b-c= (a-b)-c

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if you understand one translator
My question is how do I calculate?
A-B and  Complement of [A-B]

Comment: "Complement of [A-B]" does not make sense. For a complement you need 2 sets.